# How to print the icon and text on the same line java?

Tags: java, swing

I need to print the text and icon on the paper in Java project. My problem is the icon and text is not on the same line; the icon is little high than the text.  If I change the icon to be bigger that is on the same line. However I don’t want to change the size of the icon because the size of the icon will be bigger than the size of the text. Is there any way to do it?

My code is below:

```
package PDFAnnotationPackage;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
public class TestPrint  {  

private static JTextPane pane;
      private static  JFrame frame;
private static StyledDocument styledDocument;
       private static String txt;
public static void main(String[] args) { 
          frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    try {
        print("");
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}


private static  ImageIcon getAnotIconPrint(){
     Image image;           
     ImageIcon icon=null;   
     URL fileName=TestPrint.class.getResource("QuestionMark.gif");      
     icon=(ImageIcon)getIconImage(fileName, 12,12); 
     return icon;

}

private static ImageIcon getIconImage(URL fileName, int h, int w){
    Image image;
    ImageIcon newIcon = null;
     try {
        image = ImageIO.read(fileName);         
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(fileName); 
        Image img = icon.getImage(); 
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 15, 15, null);            
         newIcon = new ImageIcon(bi); 
    } catch (IOException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     return newIcon;


}
public static void print (String txt) throws PrinterException{

     // Create the StyleContext, the document and the pane
    pane = new JTextPane();
     Icon icon=getAnotIconPrint();
        //Icon icon=getAnotIconPrint("test");   
        styledDocument = pane.getStyledDocument();              
        Style iconStyle = styledDocument.addStyle("icon", null);
          StyleConstants.setIcon(iconStyle, icon);
          try {
              //insertIconOnDoc(iconStyle);
                   pane.insertIcon(icon);
              insertTextOnDoc(txt);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

         // pane.print();
                frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);           
          frame.setSize(360, 180);
          frame.setVisible(true);

}

    private static void insertTextOnDoc(String content ) throws BadLocationException{
        String txt="  ";        
        txt=txt+"c.author"+"\t" + "Page 2 09/09/2014" ;
        if (content!=null){
            txt=txt+"\n"+content;
        }
        txt=txt+"\n\n";             
        StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
        Style textStyle = sc.addStyle("TextFromat", null);      
        StyleConstants.setForeground(textStyle, Color.red);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(textStyle, 12);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(textStyle, "serif");
        StyleConstants.setBold(textStyle, true);
        StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(textStyle, 8);
        StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(textStyle, 0);        
        styledDocument.insertString(styledDocument.getLength(), txt+" ", textStyle); //must have space for text; otherwise the last line will not print


    }
     private static void insertIconOnDoc(Style style) throws Exception
     {
          if (style.getAttribute(StyleConstants.IconAttribute) != null)
          {
               if (styledDocument.getLength() > 0)
               {
                    Element e = styledDocument.getCharacterElement(styledDocument.getLength() - 1);
                    AttributeSet attributeSet = e.getAttributes();
                    if (style.getAttribute(StyleConstants.IconAttribute) == attributeSet
                              .getAttribute(StyleConstants.IconAttribute))
                    {
                         styledDocument.insertString(styledDocument.getLength(), " ", StyleContext
                                   .getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE));
                    }
               }
          }

         styledDocument.insertString(styledDocument.getLength(),  " ", style);


     }
```

}

The output of my code:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you display the text pane in a GUI? That is post code that displays the GUI first before doing the print. I don't feel like wasting paper to test your program. Also, have you tried the `JTextPane.insertIcon(...)` method?

Comment: @camickr I don't need to display it. In my project, I will have to print many lines as the output image according to the user selection from another JPane. My code is just list one line for posting.

Comment: It was a simple question. Does it display properly in a GUI? I am not going to attempt to debug a program by continuing to print paper to see what happens. It is much easier to test a program by getting the display to work properly in a GUI first. Then once the problem is solved you just print directly to paper.

Comment: @camickr, I changed the code as you suggested. The display is same as the print that didn't display properly. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by referencing [JTextPane Icon and Text](https://community.oracle.com/message/8598590) . I added my icon and text in the label and put it into JPanel. The JPanel put it into JTextPane. The icon and text are same height.